# In Laravel what is the difference between . and / for file paths?

Tags: laravel

I'm learning [Laravel](https://laravel.com) watching [a Laracast for beginners](https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-from-scratch-2017/episodes/6?autoplay=true). The narrator explains that when specifying a file path you can replace `/` with `.` so `my/file/path` can also be `my.file.path`.

While he explains these are interchangeable he does not explain why. It doesn't seem any faster and I haven't heard any reason how it would be a feature or any kind.

Answer (score 1):

This syntax isn't just used for file paths, this is used for any tree like structure in Laravel.

Want your application environment?  Use `config('app.env')`.

Want your app layout? use `view('layouts.app')`.

Have objects in your request?  use `request('object.property')`.

Regarding files, the one benefit I could see is this would be cross-platform,  you don't have to worry about using `\` for windows and `/` for linux.  I wouldn't really call this a feature, this is just syntax.

Comment: Okay, so like on Windows they use \ but on Unix based OS' it's /. So you're saying at least one benefit is that `.` would be cross platform?

Comment: Yes, the directory separator is different on different platforms, but I don't think that was what they were trying to resolve.  It's just the syntax they decided on for accessing trees.

Comment: Okay thanks. I'm going to up vote your answer but I'm not going to market it as the accepted answer, yet, in case others have another idea or a more certain / official one.